# Enumitem: Restart/Reset counter of new list

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I use the `enumitem` package to manipulate the appearance of my list. Because I want to keep the default `enumerate` list, I defined a new list `edulist` and configured it.

The list should be used in an environment `edulistvar`, which gives the user the ability to change the `itemsep` with an optional argument.

I want this list to resume until several points in my document are reached (see `\exercise` in the example below). Resetting the counter of the list I want to do with `\restartlist<list-name>}` which seems to exist exact for this reason:

> ## enumitem documentation
>
> Currently, with
>
> ```
> \setlist[enumerate]{resume}
> ```
>
> you can get a continuous numbering through a document.A new command
>   has been added for restarting the counter in the middle of the
>   document:
>
> ```
> \restartlist{<list-name>}
> ```
>
> It is based solely in the list name, not the list type, which means
>   `enumerate*` as defined with the package option inline is not the same
>   as `enumerate`, because its name is different.

Unfortunately, I don't get it work in the following MWE.

## Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment {edulistvar} { O{0pt} } {
  \begin{edulist}[itemsep=#1]
}{
  \end{edulist}
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand \exercise {  } {%
  \bigskip
  \textsf{\bfseries\Large Exercise}
  \medskip
  \par
  \restartlist{edulist}
}


\newlist{edulist}{enumerate}{1}

\setlist[edulist]{%
  label=\alph*),    
  format=\sffamily,
  resume=edulist,
  partopsep=0ex,
  topsep=0.5\baselineskip,
  parsep=\parskip,
}

\begin{document}

\exercise

Bli Bla Blub

\begin{edulist}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{edulist}

Bli Bla Blub

\begin{edulist}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{edulist}

\exercise

Bli Bla Blub

\begin{edulistvar}[\baselineskip]
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{edulistvar}

\end{document}
```

## Document

[image: Wrong enumeration]

Any idea how to reset the counter of the list? Manually resetting it (`\setcounter{edulisti}{0}`) doesn't work, as well.

Comment: Removing `resume=edulist` in your `setlist`-declaration should help.

Comment: changing `resume=edulist` into `resume` should work

Comment: @Hackbard_C: For sure. But as I wrote, I want the list to resume until I restart it at several points (e. g. new sections). So removing `resume=edulist` isn't a solution. ;o)

Comment: Sorry, my fault. You would have to use `\begin{edulist}[resume]`, which is not as comfortable as @cgnieder's answer, so use his recommendation! It should do the job as desired.

Comment: @Hackbard_C: No problem!
@cgnieder: This works. But: As written in the documentation, `resume` works only locally. So when I want to put my list inside an environment (e. g. `center`), it won't work without `resume=edulist`. (For some reason, I didn't get the `series` of `enumitem` to work ...) I edit my example, one moment, please.

Comment: Why would you put it in an environment?

Comment: Because I want to use the list inside an new environment, which offers some options to the user, e. g. for adding optional space to `itemsep`, without knowing about `itemsep`: `\begin{listusingedulist}[2ex] ... \end{listusingedulist}`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be as simple to patch the list environment with `\AtBeginEnvironment` and the like, from `etoolbox`?

Comment: How would you patch this? Nevertheless, this would be a (not so elegant) patch and the question is, why the code above doesn't work. And whether this behaviour is intended?

Comment: I'm running into your problem as well.  I've found that I can use `resume=edulist\thesection` to have the numbering start over for each section, which would make sense for exercises in a textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, either, but it seems straightforward to modify the MWE to do what you appear to want, if I've understood correctly, without the need for intervention by the end user:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment {edulistvar} { O{0pt} } {
  \begin{edulist}[itemsep=#1, resume=edulist]
}{
  \end{edulist}
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand \exercise {  } {%
  \bigskip
  \textsf{\bfseries\Large Exercise}
  \medskip
  \par
  \restartlist{edulist}
}


\newlist{edulist}{enumerate}{1}

\setlist[edulist]{%
  label=\alph*),
  format=\sffamily,
  partopsep=0ex,
  topsep=0.5\baselineskip,
  parsep=\parskip,
  resume}

\begin{document}

\exercise

Bli Bla Blub

\begin{edulist}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{edulist}

Bli Bla Blub

\begin{edulist}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{edulist}

\exercise

Bli Bla Blub

\begin{edulistvar}[\baselineskip]
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{edulistvar}

\begin{edulistvar}[\baselineskip]
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{edulistvar}

\end{document}
```

[image: resume and restart]

Comment: First, I thought it works. But if you add one more `\begin{edulistvar} ... \end{edulistvar}` at the end, the list will be reset, even without a new call of `\exercise`. It should continue. That's why you need `resume=edulist` (or to work with `series`, which I did't get to work inside `\setlist`).

Comment: @dawu Oops. You are right. I should have tested that. I've corrected the code and extended the MWE accordingly.

Comment: I think the problem that OP was running into is that the edulistvar environment is keeping edulist from restarting.  If you put an `\exercise` between the two edulistvar, you'll see that they don't restart.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure I understood what your problem consists in, exactly, but `series` work, even inside another environment:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*), series=edu]
    \item One
    \item Two
    \item Three
  \end{enumerate}
\end{center}

Bli Bla Blub.

\begin{center}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*=edu]
    \item One
    \item Two
    \item Three
  \end{enumerate}
\end{center}

Blibli Blabla Blubblub.

\begin{center}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*=edu, start = 1]
    \item One
    \item Two
    \item Three
  \end{enumerate}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's right. In this case, `series` works. But the user shouldn't need to take care of this. I am sorry that my question wasn't clear enought. I wanted to keep the situation as simple as possible. I hope that the problems now becomes clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is certainly to create a command to insert "Exercise" that resets the "enumerate" list counter. The "enumerate" lists must be configured to follow the numbering.. It is then "Exercise" which allows you to restart the numbering. Of course the command "Exercise" can be associated with a counter.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\Exercice}{{\noindent\Large\bfseries Exercice : }\par\vspace{0.2cm}\restartlist{enumerate}}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\alph*),resume}
\begin{document}
\Exercice
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item One
    \item Two
    \item Three
  \end{enumerate}
Bli Bla Blub.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item One
        \item Two
        \item Three
    \end{enumerate}
\Exercice
Blibli Blabla Blubblub
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item One
        \item Two
        \item Three
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

With the result :
[image]

Another solution is to use global command.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\NewDocumentCommand\currentname{}{}

\NewDocumentEnvironment {edulistvarstart} { O{0pt} } {
  \RenewDocumentCommand\currentname{}{enum-\theexercise}
  \begin{edulist}[itemsep=#1,series=\currentname]
}{
  \end{edulist}
}
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment {edulistvar} { O{0pt} } {
  \RenewDocumentCommand\currentname{}{enum-\theexercise}
  %don't know why this line is necessary
  \begin{edulist}[itemsep=#1, resume=\currentname]
}{
  \end{edulist}
}
\newcounter{exercise}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \exercise {  } {%
  \bigskip
  \textsf{\bfseries\Large Exercise}
  \medskip
  \par
  %\restartlist{edulist}
  \stepcounter{exercise}
}

\newlist{edulist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[edulist]{%
  label=\alph*),
  format=\sffamily,
  partopsep=0ex,
  topsep=0.5\baselineskip,
  parsep=\parskip,
  }
\begin{document}
\exercise
Bli Bla Blub
\begin{edulistvarstart}
  \item enum-\theexercise
  \item \currentname
  \item Three
\end{edulistvarstart}
Bli Bla Blub \currentname
\begin{edulistvar}
  \item enum-\theexercise
  \item \currentname
  \item Three
\end{edulistvar}
\exercise
Bli Bla Blub\currentname
\begin{edulistvarstart}[\baselineskip]
  \item enum-\theexercise
  \item \currentname
  \item Three
\end{edulistvarstart}
qsd qsdqs dqsd qsdqsdqsdd \currentname
\begin{edulistvar}[\baselineskip]
  \item enum-\theexercise
  \item \currentname
  \item Three
\end{edulistvar}
\exercise
Bli Bla Blub\currentname
\begin{edulistvarstart}[\baselineskip]
  \item enum-\theexercise
  \item \currentname
  \item Three
\end{edulistvarstart}
qsd qsd qsdsqq dqsd qds \currentname
\begin{edulistvar}[\baselineskip]
  \item enum-\theexercise
  \item \currentname
  \item Three
\end{edulistvar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think this works with the `edulistvar` environment.